# Change font dynamically causes problems on some components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, dynamic, fonts

first, I know how to update the font of the whole UI. I use the following code:

```
private static void setUIFont(final FontUIResource f) {
    for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().entrySet()) {
        Object key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().get(key);
        if (value != null && value instanceof FontUIResource) {
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put(key, f);
        }
    }

    dynamicallyUpdateRootPane(f);
}


private static void dynamicallyUpdateRootPane(FontUIResource f) {
        updateComponent(rootPanel, f);
}


private static void updateComponent(Component c, FontUIResource resource) {
    if (c == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (c instanceof JComponent) {
        JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
        jc.updateUI();
        JPopupMenu jpm = jc.getComponentPopupMenu();
        if (jpm != null) {
            updateComponent(jpm, resource);
        }
    }
    Component[] children = null;
    if (c instanceof JMenu) {
        children = ((JMenu) c).getMenuComponents();
    }
    else if (c instanceof Container) {
        children = ((Container) c).getComponents();
    }
    if (children != null) {
        for (Component child : children) {
            if (child instanceof Component) {
                updateComponent(child, resource);
            }
        }
    }
    int style = Font.PLAIN;
    Font f = c.getFont();
    if (f == null) {
        f = getFontUIResource(16); // default
    }
    if (f.isBold()) {
        style = Font.BOLD;
    }
    else if (f.isItalic()) {
        style = Font.ITALIC;
    }

    if (c instanceof JEditorPane) {
        ((JEditorPane) c).putClientProperty(JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, Boolean.TRUE);
    }
    c.setFont(resource.deriveFont(style));
}
```

After I set the keys I need to update my root panel recursively because not all components change its appearance. This code works almost 95%. I have some problems with JButton's and JMenuItem's.

Lets say I launch my program with a large font size and change it dynamically to a smaller one.
The font of my Buttons changes (thats good...) but when I hover them the font changes from small to big.
When I put my mouse away it changes again from big to small and I have no clue why or how to handle it, tested A LOT but nothing seems to work. There's this roll over effect and it seems that it uses a different font when I hover the element.

The other weird thing is my menu items. 
The menubar changes its font (the menus) but the menu items do not change. 
I tried to update them manually e.g. to set the font manually, but it does not work at all.

Hope you guys can help me because I spent too many hours (even days) on this.
Btw. I am using Nimbus.

Best regards

** UPDATE **

Fixed my code and my working example. Now all components on my GUI will be displayed correctly after I change the font size dynamically. Have atm. no time to clean my code but for those who are interested in a solution the code should be clear.

```
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JComboBox;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JMenu;
    import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
    import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;
    import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
    import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
    import javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource;



    public class Test extends JFrame {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1865556053669711743L;


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Test();
        }


        public Test() {
            setLaf();
            prepareFrame();
            setJMenuBar(new MyMenuBar());
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }


        private void prepareFrame() {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            final JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {
                            "Small", "Large", "Larger"
            });
            JButton button = new JButton("Change");

            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int index = combo.getSelectedIndex();
                    switch (index) {
                        case 0:
                            setUIFont(getFontUIResource(14));
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            setUIFont(getFontUIResource(16));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            setUIFont(getFontUIResource(17));
                            break;
                    }
                    pack();
                    //SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(Test.this);
                }
            });
            getContentPane().add(combo);
            getContentPane().add(button);
        }


        private void setLaf() {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    }
                    catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                                    | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private class MyMenuBar extends JMenuBar {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1434003372646915700L;


            public MyMenuBar() {
                JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("File");
                JMenu menu2 = new JMenu("Help");

                menu1.add(new JMenuItem("This is a test"));
                menu1.add(new JMenuItem("This is a test"));
                menu1.add(new JMenuItem("This is a test"));
                menu1.add(new JMenuItem("This is a test"));
                menu2.add(new JMenuItem("This is a test"));
                menu2.add(new JMenuItem("This is a test"));

                add(menu1);
                add(menu2);
            }
        }


        private FontUIResource getFontUIResource(int size) {
            return new FontUIResource(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, size));
        }


        private void setUIFont(final FontUIResource f) {
            for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().entrySet()) {
                Object key = entry.getKey();
                Object value = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().get(key);
                if (value != null && value instanceof FontUIResource) {
                    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put(key, f);
                }
            }

            dynamicallyUpdateRootPane(f);
        }


        private void dynamicallyUpdateRootPane(FontUIResource f) {
            updateComponent(this, f);
        }


private void updateComponent(Component c, FontUIResource resource) {
    if (c == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (c instanceof JComponent) {
        JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
        jc.updateUI();
        JPopupMenu jpm = jc.getComponentPopupMenu();
        if (jpm != null) {
            updateComponent(jpm, resource);
        }
    }
    Component[] children = null;
    if (c instanceof JMenu) {
        children = ((JMenu) c).getMenuComponents();
    }
    else if (c instanceof Container) {
        children = ((Container) c).getComponents();
    }
    if (children != null) {
        for (Component child : children) {
            if (child instanceof Component) {
                updateComponent(child, resource);
            }
        }
    }
    int style = Font.PLAIN;
    Font f = c.getFont();
    if (f == null) {
        f = getFontUIResource(16); // default
    }
    if (f.isBold()) {
        style = Font.BOLD;
    }
    else if (f.isItalic()) {
        style = Font.ITALIC;
    }

    if (c instanceof JEditorPane) {
        ((JEditorPane) c).putClientProperty(JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, Boolean.TRUE);
    }
    c.setFont(resource.deriveFont(style));
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `updateUI` on the components AFTER you've screwed with them...

Comment: Yes, it reverts my changes. So the button has its original size and font.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem. @camickr gave me a good hint.
Had to modify the API code to prevent some NPEs.
I do not have time to make my code "cleaner" but for those who are interested I will share my code:
All items change their size correctly now.

```
private void updateComponent(Component c, FontUIResource resource) {
    if (c == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (c instanceof JComponent) {
        JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
        jc.updateUI();
        JPopupMenu jpm = jc.getComponentPopupMenu();
        if (jpm != null) {
            updateComponent(jpm, resource);
        }
    }
    Component[] children = null;
    if (c instanceof JMenu) {
        children = ((JMenu) c).getMenuComponents();
    }
    else if (c instanceof Container) {
        children = ((Container) c).getComponents();
    }
    if (children != null) {
        for (Component child : children) {
            if (child instanceof Component) {
                updateComponent(child, resource);
            }
        }
    }
    int style = Font.PLAIN;
    Font f = c.getFont();
    if (f == null) {
        f = getFontUIResource(16); // default
    }
    if (f.isBold()) {
        style = Font.BOLD;
    }
    else if (f.isItalic()) {
        style = Font.ITALIC;
    }

    if (c instanceof JEditorPane) {
        ((JEditorPane) c).putClientProperty(JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, Boolean.TRUE);
    }
    c.setFont(resource.deriveFont(style));
}
```

** EDIT **
Added support for JEditorPanes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing your own recursive code, maybe you can just treat this like a LAF change and just invoke:

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
```

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Changing the LAF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#dynamic).

Also, there is no need to invoke revalidate() and repaint() in your code. The setFont(...) method will invoke those methods automatically.

Comment: The function performs basically the same steps as mine:

`updateComponentTreeUI0(c);
c.invalidate();
c.validate();
c.repaint();`

I updated my code once again because some components were not displayed correctly. Had to move the setFont(..) to the end of my function.

But you are right @camickr I do not need to revalidate() and repaint() because this is done by setFont(...).

My problem still exists with the JMenuItems. The size of the text just won't change.

Comment: @IoannisK., `The function performs basically the same steps as mine:` - Then use the API function instead of your own. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) using the JDK API. `Btw. I am using Nimbus` - does the JDK API work with other LAF's? Maybe it is a Nimbus bug. I don't know anything about Nimbus so I can't comment.

Comment: I edited my post. The function call to SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(..) does not fix my problem. The hover effect on the JMenuItem still exists. If I got rid of my problem I try to replace my function with the API function.